# How can I see old data after a Hyperledger Composer Network Upgrade?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to add 1 column to my mode.cto file. Once I added and apply the following commands, I was not able to see previous data:

```
composer archive create -t dir -n .
composer network install -a hash-health\@0.0.3.bna -c peerAdmin@hlfv1
composer network upgrade -c peerAdmin@hlfv1 -n hash-health -V 0.0.3
```

But, I noticed every time there is a new docker instance running.

[image: Docker ps output]

I want to see my old data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link should provide you with help around your issue https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/model-compatibility

Please be aware that Hyperledger Composer is now deprecated and you should focus on using the hyperledger fabric programming models. Of course you can continue to use hyperledger composer for education purposes if you wish

Comment: For now, I figured it out by putting 'optional' in front of a new field. I think there is another way as well that I have to find.  Yes, I saw that news as well about Composer.